# How to ensure I do not run into LeaseExpiredException

Tags: java, hadoop

Right after my job is finished running I have a program going through to upload files into S3 in chunks. I have to do some processing which is why I didn't write directly into S3. I used waitForCompletion but I'm still getting org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException for the _temporary directory which gets deleted before I use FileSystem to try to open the file.

My next option is to catch the exception and just skip the file, but is there a better option?